# Get dates between periods

Tags: t-sql

I have a table containing the following data

```
periodID periostart periodend
1        01-01-2012 10-01-2012
2        11-01-2012 01-04-2012
```

I would like for a query to return something like this.
periodID date

```
1        01-01-2012
1        02-01-2012
1        03-01-2012
etc.
1        09-01-2012
2        11-01-2012
2        12-01-2012
etc.
2        31-03-2012
```

Since I have approx 100,000 rows containing periods, I would like to work on a solution that would not influence performance (cursors, loops). Is it possible to get the result I want without using cursors or loops?

Thanks for participatin.

**I got this solution so far**

```
create table #p (id int, periodstart smalldatetime, periodend smalldatetime );
insert into #p values 
(1, '2012-01-01', '2015-01-10')
insert into #p values
(2, '2012-04-10', '2015-11-20');


SELECT TOP 366 --aprox one year
        IDENTITY(INT,0,1) AS N
   INTO #Tally
   FROM Master.dbo.SysColumns sc1,
        Master.dbo.SysColumns sc2



SELECT DATEADD(day, T.N, periodstart) AS [Date]
FROM #p
cross join #tally T
WHERE (T.N >= 0 AND T.N < DATEDIFF(day, periodstart, periodend))
ORDER BY [Date]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first **Itzik-Style Cross-Join**:

```
declare @longestPeriod int
set @longestPeriod = 1000  --you should calculate it with a single query

create table #p (id int, periostart date, periodend date );
insert into #p values 
(1, '20120101', '20120110'),
(2, '20120110', '20120120');

WITH 
  E1(N) AS (
            SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
            SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
            SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
           ),                          -- 1*10^1 or 10 rows
  E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), -- 1*10^2 or 100 rows
  E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), -- 1*10^4 or 10,000 rows
  E8(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E4 b),  -- 1*10^8 or 100,000,000 rows
  NN as (SELECT top(@longestPeriod) ROW_NUMBER() 
                OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as N  FROM E8 )
 select 
   id,dateadd( dd, NN.N , periostart) as aDay
 from
   #p
 cross join
   NN
 where NN.N between 0 and datediff( dd, periostart, periodend )
```

Each day I learn something.

**[Itzik-Style Cross-Join](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/)**:

> What's really amazing about this bad-boy is that is produces ZERO
>   READS. Absolutely none, nada, nil.

Please, John, post performance test!!!

Comment: Profiler problems, I will post the results as soon as I fix the problem.

Comment: This is basically taken from the article that I provided, but since you showed the effort to help I will mark this as solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here it is:

```
create table #p (id int, periostart date, periodend date );
insert into #p values 
(1, '20120101', '20120110'),
(2, '20120110', '20120120');


with cte as (
 select
   id, periostart as aDay
 from
   #p
 union all
 select
   cte.id, dateadd( day, 1, cte.aDay) as aDay
 from
   #p
 inner join
   cte on #p.id = cte.id 
 where
   cte.aDay < #p.periodend
)
select * from cte
```

Results:

```
id aDay          
-- ------------- 
1  2012-01-01 00:00:00
2  2012-01-10 00:00:00
...
2  2012-01-17 00:00:00
2  2012-01-18 00:00:00
2  2012-01-19 00:00:00
2  2012-01-20 00:00:00
1  2012-01-02 00:00:00
1  2012-01-03 00:00:00
...
1  2012-01-08 00:00:00
1  2012-01-09 00:00:00
1  2012-01-10 00:00:00
```

**Explanation**: I use [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) recursion to get new date adding 1 day to current date limiting to end period. Difficult is to get last generated date in recursion join, I solve this with an [OVER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause. I think that is a nice query.

**EDITED due OP comment**

I have posted this approach because OP ask for a solution with no loops and no cursors. I don't know any other way to write a sql sentence without loops or cursors that this one.

Also, I think that the **right approach to generate dates is a cursor over periods table with inner loop or with Itzik-Style Cross-Join**.

Comment: Problem with larger period spans. "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion." ??

Comment: Append this option to query: `SELECT * FROM CTE OPTION (MAXRECURSION 150);`  Change 150 by max day period. Here a sample: [Juggling With SQL](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/juggling_with_sql/2011/06/04/maximum-recursion-possible-with-cte-in-sql-server-2005-2008/)

Comment: Thanks for participating, but I found this article that explains why CTE is not the best solution for counting. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

Comment: Yes, this article is in the same page that I have link to you.

Comment: I have updated my question with a new solution, and I am currently testing performance for both solutions

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure I understand, but I think you want to use the [BETWEEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx) operator.  Something like

```
SELECT PeriodID, @Date FROM Periods WHERE @Date BETWEEN periodstart AND periodend
```

or if you are getting the date through joining to a table containing the dates, use the BETWEEN in the join

```
SELECT periodTable.PeriodID, dateTable.Date 
FROM periodTable 
    INNER JOIN dateTable ON dateTable.Date BETWEEN periodTable.periodstart AND periodTable.periodEnd
```

In this case you would have a table full of every date from earliest possible to latest possible and join the tables as shown above. A table like this could be created like so:

```
CREATE TABLE dateTable(ID int identity(1,1), Date datetime NOT NULL)
Declare @d datetime

set @d=CONVERT(datetime, '1/1/1990')--start date

While @d<=CONVERT(datetime, '1/1/2020')--enddate
Begin
Insert into dateTable values (@d)
set @d=DATEADD(dd, 1, @d)
End
```